# Memory Leak on Android Wear with fragments and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os, fragmentmanager

I have an app that has one main activity. This activity holds a reference to the fragmentManager, and all the fragments I use in my app. Once the main activity loads, it displays a "navigation fragment", this fragment holds a ViewPager which itself uses fragments to display menu items (done using a FragmentPagerAdapter). When I select a menu item (by clicking it, or using a gesture) the current navigation fragment is replaced by the menu item fragment using:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment frag, String fragTag) {

    Fragment currentFrag = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .remove(currentFrag)
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

When I return from the menu item fragment to the navigation fragment, using:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
```

I am getting big jumps in allocated memory. After selecting a menu item and returning to the navigation fragment about 8-10 times or so, my memory begins to fill up and my sensorListeners stop working so I can't use gestures. I've tried re-using fragments as much as possible and keeping the onCreateView() method of each fragment free from any instantiations.

This is what my Memory Monitor outputs when I select a menu item fragment and then return to the navigation fragment several times:

[image: loading and unloading fragments several times]

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Here's my navigation fragment 'MainFragment':

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    View view;

    private int currentPage;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private WearYFlick mYFlick;
    private WearXFlick mXFlick;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private OnShakeListener yFlickListener;
    private OnShakeListener xFlickListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        vibrator = mMainWearActivity.getVibrator();
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter((MainWearActivity)getActivity(),getChildFragmentManager());

        mYFlick = new WearYFlick();
        mXFlick = new WearXFlick();

        yFlickListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                yFlickDetected();
            }
        };

        xFlickListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                xFlickDetected();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Scrolling menu
        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.watchNavPager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
        // Set current item to the middle page
        pager.setCurrentItem(Consts.FIRST_PAGE);
        currentPage = Consts.FIRST_PAGE;
        // Set number of pages
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        // Set no margin so other pages are hidden
        pager.setPageMargin(0);

        // Set the listeners and start listening
        mYFlick.setOnShakeListener(yFlickListener);
        mXFlick.setOnShakeListener(xFlickListener);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d("FRAG", "MainFragment onPause() called");
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("FRAG", "MainFragment onResume() called");
        startListening();
    }

    private void startListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(mYFlick, Consts.GYRO);
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(mXFlick, Consts.GYRO);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(mYFlick);
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(mXFlick);
    }

    private void yFlickDetected(){
        vibrator.vibrate(Consts.vibPattern, -1);
        currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
        currentPage++;
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true);
    }

    private void xFlickDetected(){
        vibrator.vibrate(Consts.vibPattern, -1);
        // Select the current menu item
        switch (mMainWearActivity.getCurrentSelection()) {
            case Consts.MENU_ITEM:
                mMainWearActivity.replaceFragment(mMainWearActivity.getFragment(Consts.FRAG_ITEM), Consts.FRAG_ITEM);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        pager = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

And here is my menu item fragment:

```
public class VoiceFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private FragmentManager fManager;

    private WearYShake mYShake;
    private WearYFlick mYFlick;

    private TextView menuItemText;
    private ImageView mainImageView;
    private ColorStateList defaultTextColor;

    private OnShakeListener yFlickListener;
    private OnShakeListener yShakeListener;
    private View.OnClickListener imgClickListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        vibrator = mMainWearActivity.getVibrator();
        fManager = mMainWearActivity.getFragManager();

        mYShake = new WearYShake();
        mYFlick = new WearYFlick();

        yFlickListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                yFlickDetected();
            }
        };

        yShakeListener = new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                yShakeDetected();
            }
        };

        imgClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yFlickDetected();
            }
        };
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item, container, false);
        menuItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuItemFragTxt);
        mainImageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemMainImg);

        mYFlick.setOnShakeListener(yFlickListener);
        mYShake.setOnShakeListener(yShakeListener);
        mainImageView.setOnClickListener(imgClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    private void promptSpeechInput(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, Consts.PROMPT_SPEECH);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, Consts.REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Consts.VOICE_ERROR_MSG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Consts.REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    menuItemText.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d("FRAG", "ItemFragment onPause() called");
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("FRAG", "ItemFragment onResume() called");
        startListening();
    }

    private void startListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(mYFlick, Consts.GYRO);
        mMainWearActivity.registerListener(mYShake, Consts.ACCEL);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(mYFlick);
        mMainWearActivity.unregisterListener(mYShake);
    }

    private void yFlickDetected(){
        vibrator.vibrate(Consts.vibPattern, -1);
        fManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    private void yShakeDetected(){
        vibrator.vibrate(Consts.vibPattern, -1);
        promptSpeechInput();
    }
}
```

My ViewPagerAdapter looks like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private MainWearActivity context;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(MainWearActivity context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        position = position % Consts.PAGES;

        switch(position){
            case Consts.ITEM1_POS:
                return new AdapterItem1Fragment();
            case Consts.ITEM2_POS:
                return new AdapterItem2Fragment();
            case Consts.ITEM3_POS:
                return new AdapterItem3Fragment();
            case Consts.ITEM4_POS:
                return new AdapterItem4Fragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return Consts.PAGES * Consts.LOOPS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                               int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
}
```

Can anyone see why switching between my main navigation fragment and the menu item fragment might be causing such big jumps in memory allocation and stopping my sensors from working? Thanks.

Comment: When the memory usage ramps up have you tried initiating GC by clicking the garbage truck icon in Memory Monitor to see how much memory is freed?  I looked over the code you posted.  I didn't see any obvious errors.  If you want to post your main activity, I'd take a look at it.